# Flex ProgressBar Popup with bytesloaded,bytestotal

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

1)I want to progressbar popup with bytesloaded,bytestotal.
    2) i want to call this progressbar from services Action script class.

Appreciate all your helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create component with progressbar on it. Use PopUpManager to pop up your component to stage. Add properties for bytesLoaded and bytesTotal.

What kind of operation this progress popup indicates for?